# Regex to find domain name without www

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the domain name without www

ex: https://www.gmail.com/anything
Output should be gmail.com(or .net or .org)

Can anyone help me in giving a regex for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What did you try? SO is not a code generator.

Comment: i tried and my regex is (?<=\.|)\w+\.\w+$ its working in ruby not in coffescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex such as `/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\//`:

```
var str = "https://www.gmail.com/anything";
var match = str.match(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\//);
console.log(match[match.length-1]); //gmail.com (last group of the match)
```

***Note:** This will get everything after the http/https protocol, not including www - up to the first slash.*

***Extra note:** A lot of domains use sub domains - hence `mail.google.com` would suddenly become `google.com` and hence not work*. Mine includes every subdomain **apart** from `www`.

Comment: thanks and its working and the issue is i may or may not get https
ex: I may get www.gmail.com also. So how can i change that to work?

Comment: @kittuss By using questionmarks. `https?:\/\/` means "the string `http`, followed by an optional `s`, followed by `://`". Hence `(https?:\/\/)?` means the previous, but the question mark means "repeated 1 or 0 times" (so it's optional). Check my updated answer for working code. When a parenthesis starts with `?:` it's a non-capturing group, meaning "do not put this match into our match results".

Comment: match variable is null when i put this code in input blur function in jquery.. Whats wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/b33kafq4/

Comment: @sstauross You need to have something after the domain (it requires `/` in the end). `http://www.google.com` = `http:`. `http://www.google.com/` = `google.com`.

Comment: what if i don't want to have this limitation?

Comment: @sstauross Then make it optional with `?` or use the below solution by creating an `a` tag and getting the hostname off that.

Comment: ok i understand the solution below but what about the regex? what if i completely remove the \/ like this:http://jsfiddle.net/b33kafq4/2/ whats wrong with that? i want to get whatever is after the http://,https://,www. , could you help with this?

Comment: `^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)`.

Comment: That is ok, but I suggest to add `\?` at the end, otherwise it would give `null` when domain string ends without `\`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `<a>` to get information about a URL. For example:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

You can retrieve the domain with:

```
var domain = a.hostname;
```

And you can strip away any leading "www.":

```
domain = domain.replace(/^www\./, "");
```

As a reusable function, you could use:

```
function getDomain(url) {
    var a, domain;

    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;

    domain = a.hostname;
    domain = domain.replace(/^www\./, "");

    return domain;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DuK6D/

---

[More info/attributes about the HTMLAnchorElement JS object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)

Comment: Loved this. Very simple , effective and foolproof